# DataContractSerializer / DataContractJsonSerializer fails on serializing classes with Serializable attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, clr

Why does serialization fail using `DataContractSerializer` or `DataContractJsonSerializer` on classes with `Serializable` attribute?

> Exception:
>   "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer' cannot
>   be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute
>   attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider
>   marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute"

`DataContractSerializer`s works well with `DataContract`/`DataMember` attributes, but it also works with classes without those attributes except when there is a `Serializable` attribute in the class it fails, generating the exception above.

Comment: can you show your class you want to serialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, I have a private property Serializer in my class which returns System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer

```
    private XmlObjectSerializer Serializer
    {
        get
        {
            _serializer = _serializer ?? GetSerializer(GetType());
            return _serializer;
        }
    }
```

even though it is private, DataContractJsonSerializer incldue it in serialization.  Not just that property but so as private fields.  This is how it behaves when you don't specify the DataContract and DataMember attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to put [Serializable] in POCO class. It will automatically serialize your object even without putting them in your class.

Comment: yes, that's the point if serialization works without any attributes, why not work with the Serializable attribute present?

Comment: here is a post about datacontract vs serializable you may find the answer here. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/be796bd0-2502-4bd3-96d9-60bf7d68930d